# Rubber Band for Belt in Belt Drive system

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pulleys, building-physics

Looking to drive a series of belts for lateral translation using a series of pallet bands (92" rubber bands about 1" wide). Approximately 16 bands would be driven by a singular band as illustrated (roughly) below. I am hoping to use a geared up stepper motor with planetary gearbox that will respond to sound levels to effect the speed of translation. I am wondering if anyone has any advice about using rubber bands as belts in a pulley driven system, ideal arrangements for transfer of power, pulley types etc.

[image: upper zig zaging band for power distribution from stepper motor, lower bands only need to slowly tanslate]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would seriously consider using separate motors for each element. A drive train as long as that has a very high chance of causing a lot of practical problems with friction, slip and backlash as well as the difficulties of keeping everything aligned.

The chances are that a single motor would need to be significantly more powerful than the sum of individual ones due to the additional resistance of the shared drive system and the additional complexity is likely to wipe out any cost savings of one large over several small motors.

I would also be concerned about hanging the mounting point directly on a rubber belt of such a large span, even a modest load is going to cause significant sag of the belt which will further exacerbate problems with friction and alignment. This should be resolvable by using rails to support the weight of the moving elements.

If having a common drive is essential then I suggest that using a horizontal shaft driving each belt with bevel gears or a similar right angle drive system is likely to be less trouble.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I am in agreement with you. The issue is that the budget for the project is fairly small (10k). The current scheme involves about 300 of these catenary ball chains in series through a long former subway tunnel. This means that each of the 300 has two belts from which two points hang  (3 catenary loops rather than two as in the drawing above).

Comment: The movement can be very slow and subtle, I was thinking of using stepper motors with some serious gearing 100:1 to gain torque from a lower cost motor. Also, what would you think about using 1/8 or 1/16 inch steel cable and v groove pulleys to prevent more sagging? Basically I am trying to find the cheapest dumbest system for a very slow gentle translation of the hanging points. Many Thanks.

Comment: I was assuming that the mounting points would go all the way round the pulleys but from what you have said it sounds like they will just go back and forth between two points ie the motor will periodically swap between forward and reverse, is this correct ?

Comment: Chris, Thanks for the Help. You are absolutely right about the need to carry support the hanging load somehow. I was thinking that if I were to extend the bolt for the pulley and then run a tension cable between those points. The issue here becomes about how to transverse with out getting stuck at the anchor points. If I were to use a long fishing leader with swivel joints I think I could get around this. I uploaded a quick drawing here. Thanks again.    <http://imgur.com/8tefxmy>

Comment: Sorry, this links should work. <http://i.imgur.com/8tefxmy.jpg>

Comment: How much headroom do you have above the plane of the top points of the chains ?  I ask becasue your design reminds me of a harmonic pendulum ( video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVkdfJ9PkRQ ). I appreciate that this is not what you are asking for but it's something to consider.

Comment: Definitely a beautiful example, a similar behavior would be wonderful. If this thing ever comes together, I'll be sure to let you know.

Comment: I was thinking that if the subway tuner is approximately round in section you might have enough headroom that the fixing points could be pendulums. This might not give the full range of motion that you have planned for but the payoff in terms of both simplifying the designs and having an overall more fluid motion might be worth it. For exmple you could have an overhead steel cable which is 'pinged' by a lever arm at one end to send pulses of motion through the whole system. (btw I am a sculptor myself)

Comment: Hmmmm, very interesting idea... Let me see if I am on the same page, you are basically saying that the steel cable would be tensioned and plucked like a guitar string or would the lever arm swing across translating the end point of the cable, more of a big swing than a pluck. It might be nice to use some piano wire rather than string to hang, kind of makes me think of some of Len Lye's work (I guess it makes sense you would be a sculptor, haha, easy to communicate, conceptualize, many thanks)

Comment: I think that either option might work. One factor might be the practicalities of fitting anchor points and brackets to get enough tension in a cable, using torsional 'pings' would allow you to use something like a steel tube, supported at intervals with bearings. The other advantage of using torsion rather than plucking is that the motion starts of as being rotational rather than lateral oscillations so it might be more predictable to set up. I'm imagining that in either case you would be putting small pulses into the system and let the pendulums swing freely rather than driving them rigidly.